# Permissions on a mounted NFS share

Tags: php, nfs

I am trying to make a php script on a webserver write into a folder /data on a fileserver.

Apache 2.2, PhP 5.x. It's just a test configuration but I'd like to understand the thing somehow as I am not very experienced regarding permissions when it comes to webservers.

I am sharing the folder /data on the fileserver by adding

```
/data   192.168.20.6(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Mount the folder by

```
sudo mount 192.168.20.5:/data /mnt/data
```

Create a link to the webroot(does that makes sense at all?)

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/data /webroot/site1/share
```

Then I get this:

```
Warning: fopen(/webroot/site1/share/data/uploads/Fotoraum/Original/Bluehend/test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Where and how do I have to adjust permissions in a sane manner to allow the script to write into /data and its subfolders?

Thanks  a lot!

Comment: I suppose the warning is from a webserver? They typically run under a separate user, e.g. `www`. You mounted using `sudo`, hence the mountpoint is owned by `root`. Please post the output of `ls -ld /mnt/data` and `su <www-user>; touch /webroot/site1/share/foo.txt`

Comment: btw, using a mounted nfs volume might not be a very good idea: (a) if the fileserver is offline, the webservice stops working (b) network/server latency. Perhaps it's better store the files locally and then sync them over regularily?

Comment: make sure that user that is creating a link has ownership of `data` folder.

Comment: mammal here :) @sebastian   drwxr-xr-x 14 nobody nogroup 4096 Sep  9 22:36 /mnt/data

Comment: @sebastian  Doing the ls -ld on the link  gives me this  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Sep 11 21:54 data -> /mnt/data    btw the files that we put on the nfs are just the huge original files of the pictures we store. Smaller resized versions are on local storage ;) To behonest, I don't know who the www-user is...

Comment: Yes all symbolic links look like that. Did you find the username of the webserver?

Comment: @Raza the user creating the link chowned the folder /mnt/data, but of course it needs sudo to create it

Comment: su www tells me there is no passwd entry for www. su www-data asks me for a password I do not know, and I think it should not have one at all, doesn't it?

Comment: @sebastian I fixed the issue by just doing chmod -R 775 data. But I gues it wasn't very clever security wise to grant the group www-data access to the folder and all it's sub folders. The webserver won't go public but still...if someone takes over the website he could delete all files on /mnt/data, right?

Comment: if you don't know the www-data password, you can `sudo su -` and then `su www-data`. You are right in your observation that 775 perms are quite dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

per your comment I think the following option is better than `chmod -R 775 /mnt/data`

when using `mount`, you can specify the user and group which owns the files, maybe you want to use the following:

```
sudo mount 192.168.20.5:/data /mnt/data -o uid=<uid-of-www-data>,gid=<gid-of-www-data>
```

the values `uid` and `gid` of `www-data` can be found in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.

Comment: The uid and gid options do not apply to NFS mounts. (Perhaps you're confusing NTFS?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do chmod 6777 on the shared folder from the nfs server, so that any files being created on the file belongs to the owner group of the folder.